# HTTPS WCF web service on cloud

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ssl, azure

I want to create a HTTPS WCF web service on azure and want to use it in  a desktop application.

Can any one guide me in right direction to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could start with [these samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=208&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) is an article for hosting WCF service on Azure. You can use it to host your HTTPS service as well.